# kali themes and ruby progressbar error on kali linux after upgrading

Tags: kali-linux, dpkg, dependencies

when I tried to upgrade my kali linux to its 2020 version, its always returns with error code:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-themes_2020.2.1_all.deb (--unpack):
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ruby-progressbar_1.10.1-1_all.deb (--unpack): 
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ruby-progressbar/base.rb' which is also in package ruby-ruby-progressbar 1.6.0-0kali1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpgk returned with error code (1)
```

and when I finished doing sudo dpkg --configure -a, it said :

```
**dpkg**: dependency problems prevent configuration of ruby-cms-scanner:
ruby-cms-scanner depends on ruby-progressbar (>=1.9.0); however:
pacakge ruby-progressbar is not installed

**dpkg**: error processing package ruby-cms-scanner(--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

**dpkg**: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-theme-kali:
gnome-theme-kali depends on kali-themes; however:
package kali-themes is not installed.

**dpkg**: error processing package gnome-theme-kali (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

**dpkg**: dependency problems prevent configuration of wpscan:
wpscan depends on ruby-cms-scanner; however:
package ruby-cms-scanner is not configured yet.

**dpkg**: error processing package wpscan (--configure):
dependency problem - leaving unconfigured

    errors were encountered while processing:
    ruby-cms-scanner
    gnome-theme-kali
    wpscan
```

I have tried:
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install aptitude(somehow I cant install it)
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade

and I cant even purge or remove theme

what should I do? I used Virtual Box to run my Kali too. Please give me step by step of how to solve this error.

Comment: Are you using kali as a general purpose desktop operating system?

Comment: I use it for my collegue studies, so this os is very important to me, for pen test, hacking and stuff

Comment: Install Debian, for a reliable desktop system. For you pen-test stuff, just re-install kali.

Comment: omg so are you saying I cant save this os and I should make a new one?there should be another way, I mean, all of my progress is kinda in there...

Comment: I am not saying that it can't be done. But please read this https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5316/4778

Comment: Additionally, you can make a backup of your files. You won't lose everything. But yes use something else for development and as a "daily driver". Using Kali linux outside of penetration testing is like using a tank to commute to work.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1219564

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same thing, run:

```
sudo dpkg -P ruby-ruby-progressbar
```

and then continued the installation with:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install -y
```